# Cannot open include file from a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

So, I made a dll and it compiles great.
Then I referenced this dll I made in another project and received this error message:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl\ssl.h': No such file or directory
```

this .h file is used inside the dll, I would think that by referencing the dll I should not have to include this file directly...
Shouldn't a dll have all the files needed for it's purpose "inside it"?

Comment: Please [post your DLL code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here (i.e. the header files(s) and source code for the DLL) along with the code that is trying to *use* the DLL (i.e. the "another project" you mentioned). If you've "made a dll and it compiles great." then you wouldn't see this message - I'm thinking that your "another project" is including a header which tries to include `openssl\ssl.h` - i.e. it's nothing to do with the DLL, but a header-within-a-header problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because:

- A `.dll` is a **compiled, binary** file that can be [dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) at *runtime* by `.exe` programs.
- A `.h` (or `.hpp`) file contains **source code** definitions of function prototypes or data structures for your C/C++ program, which are used during *compilation*.

To compile your source code, you'd need to:

- `#include` the header file(s) so that the rest of your code knows what the data structures and function signatures stored in the DLL look like.
- Link with the `.lib` or `.a` file equivalent of the `.dll` file.

If all goes well, then the `.exe` file generated by the compilation process will be able to dynamically load in and use the (already compiled) functions stored in the `.dll` file.

Comment: but this .h is only referenced inside the dll, not from anything outside it.

Comment: If it was only referenced inside your (already compiled) DLL file, then you wouldn't be seeing this message. The compiler won't know (or care) about the source code files that were used to *create* the DLL.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't a dll have all the files needed for it's purpose "inside it"?

No. A DLL contains machine code.

The main difference between `.c` and `.h` files is that `.c` files contain **Code** and `.h` files contain **Headers** (i.e. that's what they're supposed to, although they're not bound to). You need those header files in order for the compiler to know what to look for in the DLL. After your program has been compiled and linked, the header files are not required anymore.

That's why the authors of libraries written in C or C++ which are not open source usually provide precompiled binaries as well as header files.

A file format containing machine code and headers would be possible, but to my knowledge, no such format exists, and it would be really bad if it did, because for a lot of programs that would mean **huge** executable files.

Comment: but this .h is only referenced inside the dll, not from anything outside it.

Comment: Well, obviously not. One of the files you include must try to include it.